# Gather text-data from html file

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm making an app which will display quite a lot of information in text. I would love to be able to change this text without having to do any updates to the app itself and there-fore it would be great to just get the text from a simple HTMl-file from a server and display it in a textview. Is this possible?

TL;DR: Is there a way to display text from a remote HTML-file in a textview?

-Alexander

Comment: A better idea would be using an **XML** file.

Comment: @Alexander Boman Skoug so you want to define some variable in HTML and define the same in some other file ?

Comment: @DerGolem Well I want it on a remote server so I can easily edit it

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal Not really, just straight up take the text from an html-file. The html-file doesn't need to have the tags to display/contain simple text.

Comment: If a file doesn't contain HTML tags, then it's **not an HTML** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app can send a request to get your HTML page and then set the value of a TextView to be the content of the page as shown in this example: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html